# How to explode array by multiple delimiter characters

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this:

`abc=1&def=abc||abc=xyz&xyz=1`

How can I explode it by the `&` and `||` characters?

for eg in this case the array should be

```
[0] => 'abc=1'
[1] => 'def=abc'
[2] => 'abc=xyz'
[3] => 'xyz=1'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$str = 'abc=1&def=abc||abc=xyz&xyz=1';
$arr = preg_split('#(&|[\|]{2})#', $str);
var_dump($arr);
```

will produce

```
array
  0 => string 'abc=1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'def=abc' (length=7)
  2 => string 'abc=xyz' (length=7)
  3 => string 'xyz=1' (length=5)
```

Comment: you don't have to escape a pipe inside of a class, I believe. I'd make it either `\|\|` or `[|]{2}`

Comment: I used this, since `preg_quote('|')` produces `\|`, just to be sure.

Comment: Btw you can also use this pattern: `'#(&|\|\|)#'`

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_str(str_replace('||','&',$str),$arr);
```

Comment: By the way, this will produce different array than he wants.

Comment: well, good spot. however, I'd say it's different from what is he wrote but it's more likely what's he wants